# Multilingual DB design with similar translatable fields

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, localization, internationalization

I am not in the process of designing the DB schema for a new project that I am working on.

So, the challenge is as follows:

- There is a table `Items`
- Each `Item` has a **translatable** `description_60`, `description_180` text, (the suffix number stands for the type of description that is stored, e.g 60 means 60 char long) and some fields associated to each of those such as `apiSourceName`etc.

There are two options that I see:

## 1

```
descriptions_translations

  Id
description_60
description_180
description_300
apiSourceName_60
apiSourceName_180
....
...
```

which does not look very good as we might end up with lots of NULL fields
and

## 2

```
descriptions_60_translations
  Id
description_60
apiSourceName
languageId
...
...
```

## 3 Other?

I am totally open to other recommendations!

Also, another challenge is that I want to store in the main `Item` table the `description_60` text. Is this possible without duplicating data?

**Update**
Leaning more towards this based on answers:

```
descriptions_translations
=========================
  id
itemId
description_type =>60, 120, 180 etc
`description` => 'This video is ...'
apiSourceName => youtube, dailymotion etc
languageId => en, es etc
...
...
```

Any cons against using the same column type for texts of 60 chars and 1000 chars long?

Comment: You have a 1:n relation between Item and its descriptions, so it is unfeasible to store the translations into the Items table. You can achieve this with minimal duplication, but I strongly advise against it, since you will have to maintain your values. To use some theory of relational algebra here, the composite data, storing all the translations will yield a non-atomic field, which violates the first normal form.

Comment: You can use the same column type of varchar(1000), if 1000 is the maximum. A value of 5 characters will have the size of 5 characters then, not the size of 1000 characters.

Comment: @LajosArpad - Technically, it is a 2-byte length + the 5 characters.  Still, there is no good reason to have 60/80/etc; simply have 1000.  For that matter, simply use `TEXT` (64K limit).

Comment: Perhaps the intent was short/medium/long instead of an arbitrary 60/80/120?  Do you sometimes store all 3?

Comment: @RickJames when I know that my varchar should not be longer than a certain number of characters, then its limit  is useful. When very long texts can be present (like in the case of an article), then TEXT becomes useful. Here, the question specified the limits and those limits can have valid reasons. I do not see or know more about the question, I am also speculating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a `Languages` `table`, like

> Languages(id, name)

Also, you will need an `ItemDescriptions` `table`, like

> ItemDescriptions(id, itemId, languageID, content)

You will `insert` `values` into the `Languages` `table`, like

```
60, 'English' 
180, 'Hungarian'
```

records into the Items table, like

```
1, 'Toothpaste'
```

and records into the ItemDescriptions table, like

```
1, 1, 60, 'Best Toothpaste'
2, 1, 180, 'Legjobb Fogkrém'
```

so you will have a single record in the `Items` `table` for each item, a single record in the `Languages` `table` for each language and as many records in the `ItemDescriptions` `table` as many `Languages` are they translated to.

EDIT

It turns out that there are multiple languages and multiple descriptions per language. So, we need to change the definition of `ItemDescriptions` to

> ItemDescriptions(id, itemId, languageID, content60, content180,
>   content300)

so each record will hold all the respective descriptions.

EDIT2

Since you described that you will need additional data for each description, it becomes clear that a given description will no longer be an attribute, but a record. This means that we have two possible solutions (for both solutions I avoid the definition of additional data due to lack of information, but you will be able to define their respective columns):

#### First Solution

> ItemDescriptions(id, itemId, languageID, content, maxLength)

where `maxLength` can be 60, 180, 300, respectively. Your additional values will be columns inside the `ItemDescriptions` `table`. If you use `varchar(300)` for `content`, then you will not use unnecessarily bytes to store your values in `content`.

#### Second Solution

> ItemDescriptions80(id, itemId, languageID, content)
>
> ItemDescriptions180(id, itemId, languageID, content)
>
> ItemDescriptions300(id, itemId, languageID, content)

These separate tables will store the separate values and in this case you will need separate columns in each tables with the additional data.

#### Comparison

If you use `varchar` as a type for `content`, then the first approach seems to be superior to the second one, in terms of simplicity of handling, however, whenever you `insert` or `update` a value there, you will need to make sure that `maxLength` is valid (equals 60, 180 or 300, respectively) and that `content` is not longer than `maxLength`. You can do this from your application, or via a record-level `trigger` `on` `insert` `or` `update`.

Comment: @thitami you are welcome. Please, let me know if this answers your question or if this is still not solving the whole problem.

Comment: In this case, I have to use the same column type per each `description` regardless of it being 60 or 120 or 300 or 1000 chars long? Would that be fine performance wise?

Comment: @thitami yes, you will need to do that. What does the 60, 120 and 300 mean here? Are they different language ids?

Comment: Sorry the suffix number (60/120/300/1000) is the expected length per each description. Is it still fine to use column type for those descriptions?
@Lajos Arpad

Comment: @thitami so you use a single language, but different description lengths? Translatable suggested to me that you have to translate these into several languages.

Comment: nope. So, I am using descriptions of varying length (60 chars, 120 chars etc) in different languages.
That is, I can have an `Item`, which has a different `description_60` in english and another in spanish. Then, the same `Item` can have a different `description_120` in english and another in spanish. Hope that this clears things up? :)

Comment: @thitami I think I understand you now, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Cool, @Lajos Arpad! 
But we might end up with several NULL fields here I suppose? Because, it's not sure that we will be having all available descriptions per item in all languages?


Also, we need some additional data per each translated description, e.g. description60 in english has `apiSource=youtube`, description60 in spanish has `apiSource=dailymotion`

Comment: @thitami yes, you will end up with nulls there. I wonder how it will cause you problems? If you describe your worry, I think we will find the solution.

Comment: Updated my comment, @Lajos Arpad. :)
Thing is that each description comes with `type` (60,120,...), `language` (english, spanish etc), `apiSource` (`youtube`)

Comment: updated my question. Let me know if it's any better now?

Comment: @thitami I think I am closer to understand the question. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sweet - exactly what I needed, @Lajos Arpad.
I wish I could double-upvote!

Reads are going to be significantly more than writes if that makes any difference?

Comment: @thitami yes, that's an important difference, since this means that you can create a trigger as suggested in my answer without worrying about request spikes. If writes were very frequent, then you would need to do this on application level, which is just as good at functionality level, but adds up to the difficulty to develop your site, as you will need to always keep an eye on validity on that case.

Comment: just did that ! I really appreciate that you shared your knowledge today with me! @Lajos Arpad

Answer (score 3):

A good way to do this and avoid displaying rubbish to users:

Put, in your Items table, an actual description field. For example, the US (where we are backward on weights and measures) it might be:

```
Bread, brown, 1 pound loaf
```

Then build a translation table with three columns: `lang`, `original`, translated`.

For example:

```
lang   original                     translated
 es    Bread, brown, 1 pound loaf   Hogaza de pan integral, 450g
 fr    Bread, brown, 1 pound loaf   Miche de pain brun, 450g
 de    Bread, brown, 1 pound loaf   Laib Schwarzbrot, 450g
```

Then do a query like this to fetch the translation:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t.translated, i.name) as name
  FROM Items
  LEFT JOIN Translation t ON t.lang = 'se' AND i.name = t.translated
```

That way, your Swedish customer will get the original item name (until you provide the Swedish translation), and your Mexican customer will get an appropriate translation. The trick is the `COALESCE ... LEFT JOIN` query pattern.

You may want to match translations on name id values rather than the names themselves. But, for what it's worth the localization in common systems like WordPress match on the text of the names like I suggest.

**Edit** About efficiency of using text to match rather than ids.

Let's say you have ten million items in your translation table. That will be, on average, 200 bytes per item. With indexes, let's say 400 bytes per item. That's 4 gigabytes for the table. That will cost something like USD 0.11 to 0.14 per month in a high quality cloud machine. Using an ID would be a little less than half that. Say 1.5 gigabyte.  So the difference is around USD 0.06 per month. Plus, cloud machines come with minimum storage sizes.

Lookups: If you index your tables correctly, text matching isn't hugely slower than id matching. And, it will happen not in bulk, but when people look up information.

Comment: I regret I don't know Magyar (Hungarian).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @O. Jones.
Short question about this pattern: How efficient performance-wise would be storing the whole original description for thousands (or few millions) of records?
Also, there is another param that I need to think about and that is storing translatable descriptions of various types: See comments in Lajos Arpad answer.

Comment: @thitami - Thousands -- no problem.  Millions -- it depends.  If you are mostly doing "point queries" (looking up one row by a key), no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Decide what the maximum size of a column will *ever* be, then pick from

- For "short" *fixed-length* strings (zipcode, country_code, UUID, etc), use `CHAR(..) CHARACTER SET ascii`.
- For "short" strings that will *always* be "short", use `VARCHAR(...)` with a limit that will never be exceeded.  The limit you choose does not matter much -- 60 vs 80 is inconsequential.
- For medium-sized strings, consider `VARCHAR(255)`.  (If you are using 5.5 or 5.6 and utf8mb4, use 191.)
- For longer strings, use `TEXT` (64K limit) or `MEDIUMTEXT` (16M limit).

These choices relate implementation details that, *for most users*, make no difference.

Hardly anyone need the feature of "chop off my strings at 60 characters".  If you do need such, then the application probably needs to do more than the database schema can do.